# Why is Visual Studio 2012 not giving me errors where they should be?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

**EDIT** I started a new console application to see if the features in question would work, and they did flawlessly. I guess the issue is now **why are they not working when I check out file for edit in TFS**?

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2012 and after some digging I am still having some issues. Visual Studio is not giving me the errors (red swiggly lines under the code) where they should be. I made a bogus using statement to illustrate:

[image]

The last using statement obviously isn't valid, so why isn't it telling me so?

Another example:

```
public String method()
{
    someVar = "hi";
}
```

Even though I have no someVar variable set anywhere within scope, there is no error. I am using classes obtained via T.F.S., though I doubt that matters but just in case it does I thought I would mention it.

It should also be noted that I do have intellisense capabilities enabled yet those are not functioning either.
How can I fix this madness :-)?

Comment: Even after hitting Save or Compile?

Comment: It is there after compilation, but usually they show up as they come up when you are coding, which is much more helpful to me.

Comment: Even after a while? Are your settings set to default?

Comment: Yes sir, and see the edit I mentioned. Somehow this is related to TFS

Comment: Why kind of project has this problem? Maybe a web site project?

Comment: @J-MANMORGAN why do you believe that your version control tool has anything to do with your compiler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you have not opened any project. You just opened a C# source file. Visual Studio can't provide intellisense and error detection outside of a project, except some obvious errors (like missing a semicolon).

Comment: That was it, I didn't realize that if you just opened a source file this happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to determine the ownership of the blame in this situation is to open:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced

If "Underline errors in the editor" and "Show live semantic errors" are checked, you likely are looking at a file that is not marked to compile, or isn't a part of the current solution.

If they aren't checked, one of your plugins is likely disabling them i.e.

ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings > Enable Code Analysis